# What is this substance in my canned ground beef?

Tags: canning, ground-beef

Do you know from pic what the yellow jelly like substance is on what seems to be the side surfaces of my corned beef(I can’t see it on the top or inner part)?

The ingredients say: Cooked Beef, Beef, Water, Salt, Sugar and Sodium Nitrite.

So not sure what it is.  If you say it’s fat shouldn’t it be white and solid like normal beef fat and why does it migrate to the sides, assuming it’s fat to begin with.

[image]

Product link:
https://www.penguinfresh.com/products/corned-beef-halal-canned-grace

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a jelly formed of water and proteins from the meat, primarily [collagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collagen).  More or less the same substance as [aspic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspic), though "aspic" normally refers to an intentionally created dish of this stuff, rather than a little bit forming as a byproduct of canning.

It's normal for a small amount of this stuff to form naturally at the edges of canned meat products.  It's safe to eat; there's nothing in it that isn't also in the rest of the product.  It will melt down and disappear as you cook the meat.

Comment: See also gelatin and jus/meat stock.